# Сказуемое безличного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

На одном из солидных сайтов по подготовке к ЕГЭ было размещено предложение, в котором нужно найти грамматическую основу предложения: "Их значительно больше, чем растений". Ответ, называющий слово "больше" грамматической основой, оказался неверным. Значит ли это, что сказуемое здесь "больше, чем растений"? Спасибо!

Comment: Прежде всего не стоит использовать для подготовки к ЕГЭ сомнительные источники. Понаписать можно много, вопрос, как это согласуется со "школьными" представлениями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таких предложений в ЕГЭ не будет, это уже профильный уровень. В науке их называют генитивными. Генитивные предложения часто имеют в своем составе прямые (лексические) указания на количественное значение. Эти слова или словосочетания вместе с формой родительного падежа образуют грамматическую основу предложения.Такие предложения одни учёные считают односоставными безличными,(их больше - сказуемое) другие -  двусоставными. Иногда такой генитив(род.пад.) прямо  называется подлежащим, а сам тип предложения - генитивно-количественным . Например: Воды в трюмах - 30 сантиметров (Пауст.)
Воды-подлежащее, 30 сантиметров - сказуемое. Но независимо от мнения о типе предложения грамматическая основа - род. падеж + слово, указывающее на количество, а иногда просто независимый род. падеж:Воды-то! Воды-то! Или: Ох и шуму!

В нашем случае " их больше"- грамматическая основа, а двусоставного или односоставного предложения - разницы нет, сами учёные ещё не разобрались.

Насчёт НЕТ ОТЦА-это совсем другое, это безличное предложение, сказуемое НЕТ.

Comment: Спасибо, это очень интересно, а главное - ново для меня

Comment: Это хорошо, что у грамматистов руки дошли и до подобных предложений.
Спасибо.  
Хорошо бы еще сслуку на источник приводить.
http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-026.htm

Но во всей это истории мне не нравится только одно. Фраза "Воды-то" очень напоминает предложение с опушенным главным членом: "Воды-то!"  [налилилось/поналивали]. Как получается что, грамматическая основа "переезжает"  на другое слово (слова)?

Comment: Т.е.ничего определенного. Такие же разные у лингвистов мнения, как и у нас.

Comment: Ну да, они за своё мнение "бьются", диссертации защищают, зачем им принимать чужое? У нас тоже может быть своё видение - почему нет? Мы и ученики должны принимать только то, в чём учёные не сомневаются,а не сомневаются они в одном: основа - "их больше", а из чего состоит основа - другой вопрос, от нас никто таких знаний не ждёт, любые ответы  примут.

Comment: behemothus, не совсем поняла насчёт "переезжает". Конечно, пропущен главный член, вернее, не пропущен, он здесь и не нужен, без него всё понятно, только один, второй на месте. Проблема как раз в этом и заключается: мы не можем определить,это сказуемое или  подлежащее. Поэтому кто-то сближает род. пад.с подлежащим:Воды-то!= какая большая вода!(приближено к номинативному), а кто-то приближает к безличному:как много(разлилось, находится) воды!Другие говорят о двусоставном неполном:разлилось большое количество воды.Но информация содержится именно в  слове "воды-то!", оно грамматич. основа.

Answer (score 5):

Грамматическая основа - больше. Чем растений - сравнительный оборот.  Насчет "их" - мы уже обсуждали. Ни в вузовской грамматике, ни в школьной- "их" не является подлежащим. Это дополнение. Насчет хороших  - плохих сайтов по подготовке к ЕГЭ (как и насчет пособий) могу сказать только, что ошибки и опечатки есть везде!. Ошибки, к сожалению. встречаются и в экзаменационных тестах. С ЕГЭ сама не видела, возможности нет. а вот с ГИА - сколько угодно. НО готовит-то их одна контора, и авторы те же. Грустно.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас меня закидают гнилыми помидорами, но сдаётся мне, что грамматическая основа здесь "их больше". Аналогичный ответ есть и в первоисточнике: [(A9 № 1605)](rus.reshuege.ru/test?theme=210). Глагол связка "есть" или "существует" опущен: "Их [есть] значительно больше, чем растений".

Лирическое отступление.
Интересно, а может быть предложение вообще без основы? 
Если немного изменить (просто для смысла): "Натрия больше, чем калия".
Подразумевается, что *"[Раствор содержит] натрия больше, чем калия"*. Получается, основа вообще может быть опущена. А чем этот случай лучше нашего?

Comment: Не думаю, что предложение может быть без основы.  Даже очень усеченные предложения, например в диалоге: "Ты пойдешь в кино? - А?" Здесь, мне кажется, "А?" является неполным предложением, имеющим смысл: "Что ты сказал?"
Теперь насчет "их больше". Помнится, пару месяцев назад мы обсуждали подобную ситуацию со словом "нет". На примере предложения "У меня нет отца" я предлагал считать грамм.основой "нет отца". Но тогда участники форума дружно (почти дружно) убеждали меня, что сказуемое здесь только "нет", а "отца" - дополнение. По этой логике и слово "их" является дополнением.

Comment: А в "До свидания, журавли" основа имеется?

Comment: @grumant, сделайте, пожалуйста, это вопросом.